# Why does the gradient of the BatchNorm layer be None , when I compute the InceptionV4‘s gradient useing compute_gradients？

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning

Why does the gradient of the BatchNorm layer be None , when I compute the InceptionV4‘s gradient useing compute_gradients？
When I get the gradient of the InceptionV4 model. The value of None appears in each BatchNorm layer, I'm not sure if this is an bug. Or, the BatchNorm layer would have no gradient.

```
     with slim.arg_scope(inception.inception_v4_arg_scope()):
                logits, endpoints = inception.inception_v4(images,                                         
                num_classes=dataset.num_classes, is_training=True)
     init_fn = get_init_fn()
      # Specify the loss function:
     one_hot_labels = slim.one_hot_encoding(labels, dataset.num_classes)
     tf.losses.softmax_cross_entropy(logits, one_hot_labels)
     total_loss = tf.losses.get_total_loss()
     optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate=0.01)
     grads_and_vars = optimizer.compute_gradients(loss=total_loss)
```

Answer (score 0):

I know the answer.

This error is due to the reverse order of the parameters.

The right is:

```
  tf.losses.softmax_cross_entropy(logits = logits, onehot_labels = one_hot_labels)
```